# php - question about preg_match

Tags: php, regex

I need to define a pattern so that the input string can only contain 0-9, a-z, and A-Z. Also, the length is in the range of 1-30.

Here is the script:

```
$fileBaseName = 'abc12345';

if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1, 30}$/", $fileBaseName)) {
    echo '<br/>' . 'invalid' . '<br/>';
} else {
    echo '<br/>' . 'valid' . '<br/>';
}
```

However, when I run this code, the return always is 'invalid'.

How to fix this issue?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to drop the space:

```
if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,30}$/", $fileBaseName)) {
```

Comment: Hello Matt,
Just see your rep score:)
Are you a professional web developer?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

This is the regex you're looking for:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,30}$/
```